# boost::future::then how is it implemented?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I am using futures and especially the continuations (then) a lot in other languages (javascript, python) and recently learned that something like it is also available in c++. For example like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
using namespace boost;

int main() {
    future<int> f1 = async ([]() { sleep (1); return 123; });
    future<std::string> f2 = f1.then ([](future<int> f) {
        std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
        sleep (1);
        return std::string ("foo");
    });
    f2.then ([](future<std::string> f) {
        std::cout << f.get () << std::endl;
    });
    sleep (3);
}
```

My goal is to understand how this is implemented so I was looking here:
https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/develop/include/boost/thread/future.hpp.
There is a lot of stuff going on and I think I understand most of it but there is some specific detail about all this template-magic that I don't understand and can't find in the code.

When `f1.then()` is called it creates a new future (f2) based on the return-type of the callback. If I understood correctly the callback is actually stored inside f2. When f1 gets set a result it "activates" f2 which in turn calls the callback and uses the return value to set it's own result. I think the relevant call happens here:
https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/develop/include/boost/thread/future.hpp#L4500
It seems that f2 has a `continuation_shared_state` internally that holds a reference to f1 (parent) but I don't understand how this is done. The type of f2 is just `future<std::string>` not `future<std::string, int>` or `future<std::string, future<int>>`. The type of the parent future is not part of the type of the new future but it is still stored inside it. How is this done?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question shouldn't rely on external links to be complete. Also, you need to reduce the problem first: Copy all related code from the headers into a file (resolve the `#include` statements), then start reducing things by replacing the template arguments with actual types and by plainly deleting code that's not necessary. Also, step through the code with a debugger to find out how it works.

Comment: I understand but my question is actually not about the boost implementation or even futures. My last sentence states the question which is about templates --> i just tried to give some context. Reducing code is of course a valid solution and is actually my only option if no-one can answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done with a technique called "type erasure".
This is not how it is actually done in the boost implementation but basically:
`f2` contains an object, which is a none template-type that has a virtual method that is implemented in a derived template type. This derived template type is dependent on the type of the "current" future and the parent future --> meaning it keeps the link between `f1` and `f2` without any of the two knowing about each other directly.